# How to call a Oracle Stored Function/Procedure with a list of numbers by PHP and Zend DB

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, zend-db, oracle-call-interface

This short description shows how:

1. to connect a Oracle database with PHP Zend DB
2. to call a Stored Procedure/Stored Function with Zend DB
3. to **pass a real array or a collection of integers as input parameter** to a Stored Procedure/Function (I will not pass in a string of comma-separated values)
4. to **get the result of a Stored Function**

(Note: I used Oracle 11.x, PHP 5.x and Zend Framework 1.x)

Let's go.

Create a Oracle list type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE NUMBER_LIST_TYPE IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

Create a Stored Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION MY_STORED_FUNCTION(id_list in NUMBER_LIST_TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS 
    lv_list_size number;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into lv_list_size from table(id_list);
    RETURN lv_list_size; 
END MY_STORED_FUNCTION;
```

Create a PHP file:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Db.php';
require_once 'DataSource.php';

$db_config['host'] = 'khazgoroth'; 
$db_config['port'] = 1521; 
$db_config['username'] = 'thrall'; 
$db_config['password'] = 'chuchu'; 
$db_config['dbname'] = 'orgrimmar'; // see TNSNAMES.ORA

$db = Zend_Db::factory('Oracle', $db_config);

$conn = $db->getConnection();  

$sql = 'BEGIN :r := MY_STORED_FUNCTION(:pmids); END;';

// Create an OCI-Collection object of NUMBER_LIST_TYPE
$ids = oci_new_collection($conn, 'NUMBER_LIST_TYPE');

$id_array = array(1, 12, 67);

// Append all IDs to the collection;
foreach ($id_array as $id) {
    $ids->append($id);
}

// create a statement and bind the parameters 
$stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Oracle($db, $sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':pmids', $ids, SQLT_NTY);
$stmt->bindParam(':r', $result, SQLT_INT); // this is the result of the Stored Function

$stmt->execute();

print "Result: $result";
?>
```

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that Zend_Db can't do that, but you could enhance Zend_Db implementation by bindArray method.

In plain PHP you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-array-by-name.php it works really great, you just bind php array directly to pl/sql procedure.

Comment: The description (how to) should show, that it's possible to do that with Zend_Db and a little help of oci_new_collection.